# How to write a hook to load more button from fetching a json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am calling my fake api using fetch and getting Json data.
How can I wire up my load more button so that it it loads more data?

Everything works, I just need to add functionality to that load button.
I have an empyt function...

See code below:

````
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Grid from "./components/elements/Grid";
import PetImage from "./components/elements/PetImage";
import LoadMore from "./components/elements/LoadMore";

const Main = () => {

    //state for img grid
    const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
  
    //load more pets
    //need to write a condtion allow more pets
    const loadMorePets = () => {
      ?code?
    };

    //fake api call
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('./petfinder.json')
          .then((res)=>res.json())
          .then((data)=>{
            // console.log(data); //test
            setPets(data.slice(0, 9))
          });
      },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid text="Find your pet!" >
          {pets.map( (pet, id) => (
          <PetImage
            key={id} 
            pet={pet}
            petId={pet.id}
            clickable
          />))}
      </Grid>
      <LoadMore text="Load More" onClick={loadMorePets} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```THANKS!
````

Comment: Put the fetch in a function and have the onclick and the useEffect call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already have all the data but you need to dispaly it in pieces? How about this.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Grid from "./components/elements/Grid";
import PetImage from "./components/elements/PetImage";
import LoadMore from "./components/elements/LoadMore";

const Main = () => {

    //state for img grid
    const [allPets, setAllPets] = useState([]);
    const [petCount, setPetCount] = useState(9);
  
    //load more pets
    //need to write a condtion allow more pets
    const loadMorePets = () => {
      setPetCount(allPets.length)
    };

    //fake api call
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('./petfinder.json')
          .then((res)=>res.json())
          .then((data)=>{
            // console.log(data); //test
            setAllPets(data)
          });
      },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid text="Find your pet!" >
          {allPets.slice(0, petCount).map( (pet, id) => (
          <PetImage
            key={id} 
            pet={pet}
            petId={pet.id}
            clickable
          />))}
      </Grid>
      <LoadMore text="Load More" onClick={loadMorePets} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for taking a look, I tried the solution above, and I get a infinte loop error.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? Here is a working fiddle with the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tdd-415uh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it works in the codesandbox, but it does not work in my app. I get an error message stating, too many re-renders, stuck in a loop.... not sure what the issue is, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @cyberAnn You are calling load more on render with onClick={loadMorePets()} in line 86, remove the ().

Comment: I am sorry, but nothing renders.... thanks for trying tho.

Comment: I finally fixed my issue.... and your solutions was very helpful, I was able to to fix it by testing but I used about 98% of your solution, I just needed to add this to my load function: 
```const loadMorePets = () => {
         loadSetPets(loadPets + 8)
    };```

Answer (score 0):

Create another hook to store the entire data from the api, and in the useEffect store the full data in that hook.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('./petfinder.json')
          .then((res)=>res.json())
          .then((data)=>{
            // console.log(data); //test
            setPets(data.slice(0, 9))
            setData(data)
          });
      },[])
```

This way you can redo the slice again without calling the API a second time

```js
const loadMorePets = () => {
      setPets(data.slice(0, 18))
    };
```

you can also keep track of your min/max slice values in a hook as well, and edit them as you see fit in the load more

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tired it, but I am stuck in a loop...